# How can I set a URL for my description field in discord.js 13 embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted to make an embed that contains a description with a URL on
it. But I am getting an error:

```
RangeError [EMBED_DESCRIPTION]: MessageEmbed description must be a string.
```

My code:

```js
player.on('trackAdd', (queue, track) => {
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()    
    .setTitle('Queued')
    .setDescription({text:`${track.title}`, URL: (`${track.url}`) })
    
    queue.metadata.send({embeds: [embed]});
});
```

I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a string to [`setDescription`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setDescription), it won't accept an object.

You can use Markdown syntax to [create a link](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links) though:

```js
.setDescription(`[${track.text}](${track.url})`)
```

It will display a link where the URL is `track.url` and the link is `track.text`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview), you can use `embed.setURL('https://somedomain.tld')` to achieve what you want.